# Buildfire: Custom Designs and Chat Plugin

Tags: buildfire

I am using the buildfire Whitelabel client's account and I want to know the answer's to the following questions

1. How can we customize the Sidemenu, Navbar, etc like the below screenshot
   [SideMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seEcX.png) [Bottom Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrEp8.png)
2. Is there any plugin for mobile number verification?
3. Please let me know how we can use this plugin, as we can't find this on the plugin
   marketplace [Chat Plugin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD8Ww.png)
4. Also, after pushing app to testflight we see that app is looking different in testflight and different in the buildfiire testing console, i cant attach the screenshot of the app here but let me if we can share it somewhere on email, we know this is the device size issues, so can we upload svgs image? or can you give use design guidelines, as we are following this https://learn.appdocumentation.com/en/articles/2195862-branding-page-tutorial but still feel images are not looking proper, so give us proper guidance
5. Please let me know how we can add a custom screens before login and register screens,  with buttons